# How can I export this value into another JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, import, export

I am trying to export a variable from one JavaScript file to another

```
const ticketsForFilm = document.querySelector(".film-list")

// FUNCTION FOR GETTING THE FILM ID FOR BUYING TICKETS
export let filmID 
function choosingFilmForTickets(e){
    let target = e.target
    if(target.classList.contains("fa-ticket-alt")){
        filmID = target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id
    }
} 

// LISTENER FOR GETTING THE FILM ID WHEN CLICKING ON THE TICKET ICON
ticketsForFilm.addEventListener("click", choosingFilmForTickets)
```

This is my code for getting an ID of a film once an icon is clicked, however this is also when my html file changes to another one for next steps.

When I try to export and import the filmID variable in the other JS file

```
import {filmID} from "../films.js"

console.log(filmID)
```

I get the error
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Your `ticketsForFilm` is `null` so there is no element with `.film-list` class, either because you don't have any such element or either you are executing JS before DOM initialization

Comment: It is not null in the first html where the event is fired upon click. For example, when I put console.log(filmID) inside the if statement, just before the html page is changed the correct value is logged in the console. The error is from the second html page.

Comment: The problem is this row `ticketsForFilm.addEventListener("click", choosingFilmForTickets)`, the error states that your `ticketsForFilm` is null, at least I can infer this from the code you provided. With *"just before the html page is changed"* what do you mean? By changing or refreshing the page you loose every variable value

Answer (score 2):

Try saving the value in local storage, Then it would be accessible across all js files

Here are some links
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done and it works perfectly. Thanks